# Can we change Noise seed per sample in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction

In cycles, I have noticed that instead of taking 1000 samples, we can take just 10 renders of 50 samples each with different noise seed and average them externally, the noise goes down A LOT. So, is there a way to do this same thing per sample rendering soo that cycles automatically averages it out?

Comment: can you show us the image? preferably with comparison.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Average of 12 images 128 samples each - https://imgur.com/a/UJwpgTs. 1 image with 1536 samples - https://imgur.com/a/zmWPmzI. Zoom in the area where the wick touches the oil. There, the difference is obvious.